# Unity repository with inherited class library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, repository, unity-container

My project have Two class libraries and one web client they are respectively : A,B and Client

[image]

when i invoke Save() method show me error.

```
new B().Save("Input");
```

Note:how to use Unity in this class library.

Client call Library A method **Confirm()** and Library A call Library B Method **Save()**
Library B method save data in **database**.

Now I want to use Unity repository container in Library B,But how? [This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/inversion-of-control-using-unity/) article help me to understand how to use repository with console application,but failed to apply this with my situation.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is registering dependency injections at the top level of your application, like mvc/webapi applications. Any explicit resolve in a class library breaks the dependency injection chain, hides dependencies. If you need to use the container directly in your class library, you probably need to redesign your solution.

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    public MyApiController(IService service)
    { 
        //clearly MyApiController depends on IService
    }
}

public class MyService : IService
{
    public MyService(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.Dependency1 = container.Resolve<Dependency1>();
        //using container directly breaks the dependency chain
        //because I can resolve everything here
        //makes MyService hard to be injected and unit tested 
    }
}
```

Comment: Danny Chen,thanks for your reply,for lack of my knowledge please forgive me.I don't understand how you do MyService constructor dependencies. When my Library A Call Library B,This called process must me new B().Save().So how you resolve B's constructor dependency.

Comment: @shamim If you use `new B()`, you are not doing things in the dependency injection way. I'd suggest you to read some guidance articles. You can get them easily via search engine.

Comment: thanks for your reply, with out newB() how to call inherited library methods.As i told earlier in my questions and picture.